# How does CGI recognizes compiler?

Tags: javascript, cgi, wsgi

This question might seem really silly to most of the enlightened folks here. But believe me, I am asking this because I couldn't find answer by normal google search and thus resorting over here. I know CGI is language agnostic. Since I am not in web development, I was just wondering how does the web-server knows which compiler to look for if we have multiple cgi scripts among which one may be python script while other might be C and so on and so on?

Comment: It's important to note that web servers usually cannot directly execute C code; they do not compile C themselves. Rather, C must be compiled by the user before the web server can utilize it as a CGI script. (There are [exceptions to this](http://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html#SEC3), but it is usually the case that C must be compiled manually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in CGI about that.  Each web server does it differently.  For example, Apache has an entire [configuration language](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/configuring.html) for specifying how requests are processed, filtered, and routed to handlers.  By contrast, a python [simple HTTP server](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) has no concept of CGI scripts, and just calls methods on a python object to service requests.

EDIT:

CGI usually means [RFC 3875](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875).  That document never requires  web servers to associate files on a local file system with URLs.

The bit that comes closest to talking about scripts is

> **3.4.  Execution**
>
> The script is invoked in a system-defined manner.

which basically allows servers to delegate to scripts if they like or do anything else they like to service requests.

Comment: Does this mean CGI script is just a plain text file and the responsibility to identify the proper compiler lies solely upon the web-server? I was even thinking if shebang line in python might have anything to do with this :D

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades, I aded an EDIT about RFC 3875 and how much latitude it gives servers.

Answer (score 2):

CGI scripts are run by the operating system.

Web servers usually assume a file is a CGI script if it's in a certain directory (often named `cgi-bin`) and has the executable bit set.

If the web server thinks the file is a CGI script, it `fork`s, sets some environment variables and other little things and then asks the operating system to execute it.

The operating system sees if it can execute it directly, and if it can, then it does. Otherwise, it looks for a [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) and uses that to execute the script.